# Dynamics CRM wait condition timeout convert to utc time

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm using workflow wait condition to update field in Entity. I have datetime field and when actual time is  2 days before this field value ,I want update another field in this entity. In CRM settings time zone is +1 UTC. So, this workflow wait condition works okay, only if I choose 2 days and 1 hour, but not just 2 days. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom workflow action that takes the number of days as an input parameter, calculates the adjusted wait period (ex: 2 days and 1 hour becomes 2 days), and then sets the result as an output parameters for use in the workflow's wait condition.